# Difference in Difference using Fama-French Five Fector

Tags: difference-in-difference

I am not quite sure if I apply the Difference in Difference Method correctly and hope someone can have a look on it.

I am investigating the impact of Investments in FinTech on banks stock return using the Fama-French Five Factor Model add adding the Investment Volume as IV. Now I want to investigate if there is a different impact of Investment Funding on the banks stock return if they whether have a Chief Digital Officer or not. Therefore, I added the dummy variable (1 = yes; 0 = no). My interaction term is Investment Volume* CDO.

Running the regression I am looking at the Investment Volume to see if it has an impact on the banks stock return at all (both banks, no matter if a CDO exists or not), afterwards I do the same for the CDO dummy variable to see if it impacts the banks stock return and finally I look at my interaction term to investigate if banks with a CDO are similary or differently impacted by the Investment Volume.

However, I am not quite sure if I conducted this correctly as my control group are all banks regardless of if a cdo exists or not.

I hope this becomes clear and someone can help me with this issue.

Comment: Welcome. Could you describe how you coded your measure of volume? And what do you mean when you say all banks are in your control group? Maybe show us the code you ran as well, if possible.

Comment: Hello @Thomas Bilach, 

my measure of volume is the logt-logt-1. Here is the code that I used: 

`reg rirf mktrf smb hml cma rmw logfund cdo logfundcdo, vce(cluster company)`

rirf = stock return
mktrf, smb, hml, rmw and cma == FF5-Factors
logfund = Growth rate of the Investment Volume
CDO = Dummy Variable (1 they have a CDO, 0 otherwise)
logfundcdo = logfund*cdo (Interaction variable to measure the Difference-in-Difference)